# Saving next line to .mat

Tags: matlab

I need to save some data to an existing table. So i have column names and one row that has data. Now I get the second set of information and i need to put it in the second row and so on. 
Can you just point me where i can find this.
I have done this so far. Played arround with save( -struct) but doesn't seem to work.

```
if exist('table.mat','file')
...
...
else
    dataCell = [name,trez,score];
    colNames = {'Name','R','G','B','Shape'};
    uisave({'colNames','dataCell'},'table');
end
```

So I check if there is `table.mat`, if there is none it creates it with some passed values. Now `table.mat` exists I need to put the second values without deleting other values.

**UPDATE**

OK i made the code like this:

```
if exist('table.mat','file')
        dataCell = [name,num2cell(trez),num2cell(score)];
        save('table.mat', '-append','dataCell');
    else
        dataCell=[name,num2cell(trez),num2cell(score)];
        colNames={'Name','R','G','B','Shape'};
        uisave({'colNames','dataCell'},'table');
    end
```

But when i do save data using :

```
   dataCell = [name,num2cell(trez),num2cell(score)];
   save('table.mat', '-append','dataCell');
```

It deletes the old entry. Lets say in my table information is as it follows :

Name | R  |  G  |  B  | Shape  |

Orange | 239  | 135  | 2 |  0.87

Then if I try to save another entry like :

Apple  | 100 |31  |56 | 0.79

It deletes the Orange. So do i need to add something or use some other method for this kind of information saving?

Comment: The complete code can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493320/determine-a-regions-average-in-matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `save` command can take an `-append` flag, which allows you to add data to existing files without overwriting old data. However for .mat files `-append` only allows you to add new variables. If you specify a variable name that already exists in the .mat file it will be overwritten.

However, if you are saving to an ASCII file then data is simply appended to the end of the file.

This presents you with two options.

1. Save using a .mat file, but for each variable you want to save you would need to load any variables with the same name from the .mat file, combine old variable with the new variable and then resave it to the file.
2. Save the matrices using an ASCII format, and then convert the from ASCII when you load the file.

**Update**: After re-reading your original question, I have to ask why not save in a single operation rather than saving line by line?

Comment: When you open and start writing to it make sure you set the options correctly. Make sure you open it in read and write mode, don't want to open it for writing and erase everything. And to use the -append the file has to exist, so you'll have to create it before you can append to it. Just a heads up if you want to try/or are going to do things a little differently.

Comment: Because i am creating a recognization aplication and i need to store data from learning to a table. Then using KNN i need to look into that table to find the closest one. Ill try with -append flag.The data stored is: Name of the object, RGB colors and roundness of and object. Thanks for the help.